# model IntegerField() to django-template with ordinal

Tags: python, django

I have a model with IntegerField()

```
class Room(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    floor = models.IntegerField()
```

And i would like it to display in a template with ordinal suffix.

```
{% for room in rooms %}
    <div>
        <p> {{ room.type }}</p>
        <p> {{ room.floor }} </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like the floor output like this.

`1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th... 10th.. 12th.. 13th.. 15th...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ordinal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/humanize/#ordinal) function from django.contrib.humanize package

Answer (score 2):

add `django.contrib.humanize` to your installed Apps
for more details [django.contrib.humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/humanize/)

Comment: The already accepted answer also suggested this package and named a useful function from it. You should [add more context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).